# Loading ARX module fails without information

Tags: autocad, objectarx

I am working with old software, in which I have a C++ project that builds a `.arx` module for AutoCAD 2023. When trying to load the module into AutoCAD, I get the following error message:

*I have removed part of the path in the error message for integrity reasons.*

```
Command: (ARXLOAD "D:/dev/projects/.../module.arx")
d:\dev\projects\...\module.arx cannot find a dll or other file that it needs.
; error: ARXLOAD failed
```

The message never tells me what dll or file that is missing. I have doubled checked the dependencies and I can not seem to find any missing .dlls.

Is there a way to troubleshoot AutoCAD or the module, in order to find more information about which dependency is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the most likely reason. Using a dependency walker is your best option
I like to use this https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

You can add search directories so you can eliminate the AutoCAD dependencies